# How to display a repeated image stored in database on background as on Twitter?

Tags: php, html, css, image, temporary-files

I want to display an image on background (by using CSS repeat) the same way as on Twitter but the problem is that I am retrieving it from a MySQL database and CSS cannot handle the `src` tag on background.

How can I retrieve an image from the MySQL database (I know how to display image by retrieving from database but here I want to display it differently), i.e display the image as backround on body and the  image should repeat as if CSS `repeat` statement were used. Like on twitter.com.

My code is is in PHP and MySQL. I need to get the URL for as this image is retrieved from a database.

Comment: In what form is the image stored in the database? Is it just the image's path (.e.g `/images/some-image...`) or a base64 string representing the actual image?

Comment: @user1938039 - you can look at [this one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/)

Comment: @PankitKapadia sir is it possible to store the image in a tmprry file when it is retrieved and then use the background-image: url thing?

Comment: @user1938039 - what exactly you are trying to do? you asked for the image to be retrieved from the database and using it into css. Better you explain what exactly you trying to do !

Comment: i have retrieved the image using database so now i want to use css repeat command and set it as backround so a css needs url so now i was wondering if it is possible to first store the image in a temprry file  and use it in our url @PankitKapadia

Comment: @user1938039 - as far as i got you, you can upload image and store it in a directory. and give the path to that directory to display it. [**Here**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) you will find how to upload a file and how to get the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot repeat `<img src="#" />` so for that you need to use CSS in your PHP document, you can do it like

```
<style>
body {
   background-image: url('<?php echo $whatever; ?>') !important;
   background-repeat: repeat;
}
</style>
```

Either you can do is

Make a stylesheet with a `.php` extension.

Than `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/stylesheet.php' />`

At the top of the page mention this

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
?>
```

Now you can set variables accordingly

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    $background = "$imgsrc"; /* Retrieve your image here */

    /*Now simply use the $background variable for setting the body background */
?>
```

Comment: no it cant work because here in url u have to give address in your directory but my image is in database so this surely cant do the job sir @Mr. Alien

Comment: please suggest some answer sir

Comment: You can base64 encode your blob image and include it directly into the markup as a data uri..be sure as it's not supported much on IE8 and earlier

Comment: sir is it possible to store the image in a tmprry file when it is retrieved and then use the background-image: url thing?  @Mr. Alien

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps.

Create a PHP script that accepts a parameter to identify through a unique ID, which Row has the image to display.  This script will extract the image from database and send the codes with appropriate mime-type, so that browser understands.  This way, apply a class to the container (or body tag) and display the background like:

```
.backgroundTile { background-image: url('/path/to/php-image-render-script.php?image_id=1212') !important; background-repeat: repeat; }
```

Example PHP Script (Source- [http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_an_image_stored_in_a_database_*PHP*-16637.html](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Display_an_image_stored_in_a_database__PHP_-16637.html)  ) :

```
<?php require_once('Connections/testConn.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$colname_getImage = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['image_id'])) {
  $colname_getImage = $_GET['image_id'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_testConn, $testConn);
$query_getImage = sprintf("SELECT mimetype, image FROM images WHERE image_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_getImage, "int"));
$getImage = mysql_query($query_getImage, $testConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_getImage = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImage);
$totalRows_getImage = mysql_num_rows($getImage);
header('Content-type: ' . $row_getImage['mimetype']);
echo $row_getImage['image'];
mysql_free_result($getImage);
?>
```

Comment: sir is it possible to store the image in a tmprry file when it is retrieved and then use the background-image: url thing?

Comment: you dont need to save it in a temporary file using this method. temporary file will be messier because you will have to take care of temporary file deletions and management on server too.  try this out, its pretty simple. the script just outputs the content of the image