# how to get the image which is taken from mysql as backround in body?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display a repeated image stored in database on background as on Twitter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109295/how-to-display-a-repeated-image-stored-in-database-on-background-as-on-twitter)

I want to display an image on background (by using CSS repeat thing) the same way as on twitter but the problem is that i am retrieving it from a MySql database and CSS cannot handle src tag on background i have usedfollowing code and links

```
body{
    background:url(<?php $lastid=$_SESSION['lastid']; echo "get_test.php?id=$lastid";?>)     repeat;

   }
```

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?210964-Set-CSS-Background-Image-with-PHP

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood/

my whole code on the main site

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
?>
<style>
  body{
    background:url(<?php $lastid=$_SESSION['lastid']; echo "get_test.php?id=$lastid"; ?>) repeat;

   }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File:<br>
<input type="file" name="image">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">

</form>



<?php

mysql_connect("host", "nam", "database") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

$file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size = addslashes(getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));

if($image_size==FALSE)
{
echo "thats not an image";
}

else
{

mysql_query("INSERT INTO image_store VALUES ('','$image_name','$image')") or die(mysql_error());
 $lastid=mysql_insert_id();

$_SESSION['lastid']=$lastid;
 echo "the image is"."<image src=get_test.php?id=$lastid>";


}

?>
</body>
```

and the code on get_test.php is

```
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "nam", "database") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());


$id = addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM image_store WHERE id=$id ");
$image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image = $image['image'];

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: So.... what's the problem?

Comment: what does the generate html look like?

Comment: this is not working sir please help me to figure out problem the method or suggest a way for same...i am quite new to this please help sir @DavidHarris

Comment: Well for starters, does your get_test.php file send an image header? Like `Content-Type: image/jpeg`?

Comment: yes sir it do i have tried it while inserting in database @DavidHarris

Comment: And does your row in the database have binary data which can be output using `imagecreatefromstring()`?

Comment: echo "the image is"."<image src=get_test.php?id=$lastid>"; this worked sir but i dont know why above one is not working

Comment: sir i have stored in blob

Comment: Try adding a space after the very last semi-colon, before the closing PHP tag, so it looks like `; ?>` instead of `;?>`

Comment: i dont want to repeat the image in backround...and is there any way that url can act safely for get_test.php?id=$lastid"; as src is doing

Comment: @DavidHarris no sir that didnt worked

Comment: You need to be **more clear** on what the issue is. All you have told me is that it "didnt work". I don't know what I'm supposed to be doing, just swinging a knife in the dark.

Comment: sorry sir, i retriev an image from a database from another page i.e get_test.php also i give a id whose image i want to rcv then i want to display that image in my body backround and thats whats my main problem @DavidHarris

Comment: sir i will rightaway put my whole code here just wait for 2 more sec. @DavidHarris

Comment: sir here i have igiven the whole related data now please see if you can help @David Harris

Comment: @DavidHarris sir i have done whole edditing atleast have a look to this please

Comment: As another user said, what is the HTML it generates?

Comment: sorry sir i didnt get your point@DavidHarris

Comment: You have a <pre> tag in your <head> tag, remove it. View the source (after it's been generated) and pastebin it or post it here.

Comment: sir yes thats mistake while cpying that is not in my code @DavidHarris

Comment: @DavidHarris have u come across any solution sir?

Comment: in your browser, if you view source, what is the html code you see for the background image

Comment: How many times are you going to post the same question? - [how to retriew an image from mysql database and display the image as backround on body? closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112596/how-to-retriew-an-image-from-mysql-database-and-display-the-image-as-backround-o) AND [How to display a repeated image stored in database on background as on Twitter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109295/how-to-display-a-repeated-image-stored-in-database-on-background-as-on-twitter)

Comment: its not same @Sean so please mind your own business dont freak me if u cant help others please stop annoying them

Comment: @box86rowh sir this is being displayed get_test.php?id=

Answer (score 0):

To answer this:

1: Add a space after the last semi-colon. This has caused issues with people before.

2: To stop the background from repeating, use the `background-repeat` property, and set it to `no-repeat`, like this:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: no sir that didnt worked i checked out @David

Comment: Well I'm sorry, you're not telling me what the issue is so I cannot help you.

Comment: sir here i have igiven the whole related data now please see if you can help @David Harris

Answer (score 0):

In order to set/use a `$_SESSION` variable (ie `$_SESSION['lastid']`, you need to start a session on each page-

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
?>
<style>
  body{
    background:url(<?php $lastid=$_SESSION['lastid']; echo "get_test.php?id=$lastid"; ?>) repeat;
   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```